# Strange url generated by AngularJS $resource

Tags: angularjs

In my AngularJS app, I have this $resource definition...

```
userApp.factory('ISBN', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
return $resource('/api/search/isbn/:isbn', {
        isbn : '@id'
    });
}]);
```

...which I would expect, when called like this...

```
$scope.Details = ISBN.get ('9780000000007');
```

...to compose a URL that looks like:

```
/api/search/isbn/9780000000007
```

But it doesn't. It looks like this:

```
/api/search/isbn?0=9&1=7&10=0&11=0&12=7&2=8&3=0&4=0&5=0&6=0&7=0&8=0&9=0
```

I have other $resource's defined in similar ways and they behave as I would expect. I'm a bit stumped by this one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: Try using : `$scope.Details = ISBN.get({isbn: '9780000000007'});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `ISBN.get('9780000000007')`, you should use `ISBN.get({id: '9780000000007'})`.

You should pass an object to the `get()` function, and you have specified with `@id` which key should be the identifier key of the resource. Additional fields are appended to the URL as query string.

The reason why you got that strange URL is because the string that you passed is also an object in javascript, with numerical key and a value for each character. These are appended as query string to the URL.

Comment: Thank you! Been staring at the screen, and couldn't see wood from trees! Just altered it to `ISBN.get({isbn: '9780000000007'})`

Comment: You're welcome, I edited my answer to explain the result of the error you made a bit more. BTW: I think that you should either replace `isbn:` by `id:` (in your comment above), or replace `@id` with `@isbn`.